# Unable to access Port 8080 on Mac

Tags: macos, vpn, proxy, macbook

```
Mac version: macOS Big Sur , 11.2.3
```

Even after

1. Shutting Down/ Restarting
2. Killing all the process running on 8080 port

Whenever i am trying to access `localhost:8080` , it always says

```
This is a proxy server. Does not respond to non-proxy requests.
```

Comment: Are running a webserver on 8080?

Comment: I am trying to run a webserver on 8080 but it shows "This is a proxy server. Does not respond to non-proxy requests." @MarkScheck

Comment: Which webserver and can you post the logs?

Comment: the logs says port 8080 already in use. but i couldn't find what process is using it. @MarkScheck

Comment: Open a terminal and netstat -arn |grep 8080  should tell you. Also what webserver is it? I found some tomcat docs that looked the same.